# When using the Alamofire.upload method with Alamofire 4.0.0, an error returns and i cannot find the solution

Tags: xcode, swift3, alamofire

```
if let img = ImageSelectorImg.image , imageSelected == true{

            let urlStr = "https://post.imageshack.us/upload_api.php"
            let url = URL(string: urlStr)!
            let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2)!
            let keyData = "AEHKL...66b".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            let keyJSON = "json".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

            Alamofire.upload(.POST,url,multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imgData, name: "fileupload", fileName:"image", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: keyData, name: "key")
                    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: keyJSON, name: "format")
                },

                encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in

                    switch encodingResult {

                    case .success(let upload, _, _):

                        upload.responseJSON { response in

                            if let info = response.result.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

                                if let links = info["links"] as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> {

                                    if let imgLink = links["image_link"] as? String {
                                        self.postToFirebase(imgLink)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    case.failure(let _): break
                    }
            })
        }
```

When i run the code above, the error "Ambiguous reference to member 'upload'(_:to:method:headers:)" appears and im not sure what the solution is to this. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parameter for url and remove method name.

```
Alamofire.upload(
multipartFormData: {multipartFormData in
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imgData, name: "fileupload", fileName:"image", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: keyData, name: "key")
                multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: keyJSON, name: "format")
            },
to: "https://httpbin.org/post", //URL,
encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
    switch encodingResult {
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        upload.responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
        }
        upload.uploadProgress(closure: { //Get Progress
                progress in
                    print(progress.fractionCompleted)
            })
    case .failure(let encodingError):
        print(encodingError)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using older `upload` syntax. It should be:

```
if let img = ImageSelectorImg.image, imageSelected {
    let urlStr = "https://post.imageshack.us/upload_api.php"
    let url = URL(string: urlStr)!
    let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2)!
    let keyData = "AEHK...d66b".data(using: .utf8)!  // key removed for sake of privacy
    let keyJSON = "json".data(using: .utf8)!

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(imgData, withName: "fileupload", fileName:"image", mimeType: "image/jpg")
        multipartFormData.append(keyData, withName: "key")
        multipartFormData.append(keyJSON, withName: "format")
    }, to: url, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                if let info = response.result.value as? [String: AnyObject],
                    let links = info["links"] as? [String: AnyObject],
                    let imgLink = links["image_link"] as? String {
                            self.postToFirebase(imgLink)
                }
            }
        case.failure(_): break
        }
    })
}
```

Note, the `method` parameter defaults to `.post`, so you don't have to supply that.

Comment: See [upload documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/4.2.0/Functions.html#/s:F9Alamofire6uploadFT17multipartFormDataFCS_17MultipartFormDataT_14usingThresholdVs6UInt642toPS_14URLConvertible_6methodOS_10HTTPMethod7headersGSqGVs10DictionarySSSS__18encodingCompletionGSqFOCS_14SessionManager31MultipartFormDataEncodingResultT___T_) or [upload example in README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#uploading-multipart-form-data).